# employment background check (error due to old version of resume)

Tags: background-check

I had an interview for "Position A" last month but with no success. Recruiter called me again and asked me whether I'm interested in "Position B". I said yes.

The recruiter used the resume for "Position A", and meanwhile, I moved to other company.

I got verbal offer for "Position B", and background check will be done later.

In the resume, it says I'm still working for old company. What happens during the background check process if there is 1~2 months gap from the most recent employment?

Comment: Why not send them an updated resume?

Comment: I quit the old job on May 1, and the new job started beginning of this month, June. Do you think I should send the resume anyway?

Answer (score 5):

What will happen is very company specific.

Every time I have had a background check done it has had a separate form that I had to fill out for the third party provider.  If you need to fill out a form just list the new employment (1-2 months) and go about your day.  If you do not get the opportunity to fill out a form for the background check and you want to be preemptive, let your new employer know they were given a slightly out of date resume and you have another position starting on xxx to currently.

Overall I would not see it as an issue since you are not claiming a degree or something in your past that did not happen, just information is a bit out of date from what is currently going on.  However since this is entirely company specific it would be hard to give any better answer.

Comment: I think the only issue here is that the OP is jumping jobs after a month.  Whether or not that appears on the background check is going to be far less of a concern for the company than determining *why* the OP is looking again so soon.

Comment: @NotMe  I would agree.  However if this is the first time OP, could have just landed a bad job and be just fine.  Since he stated he had a verbal offer I did not address that issue.