# Forgot to bring an updated copy of my resume to an interview

Tags: job-offer

I applied to work at a company about a month ago and started their interview process. Finally got the offer today and noticed that they plan to do a background check based on my resume.
However, the resume they're checking with is out of date and I was asked to leave the last company I worked at. Should I proactively send an updated resume to the recruiter upon accepting the offer, explaining the situation, or should I simply accept the offer as it's made and not say anything?

I feel like it's good to be honest, but I also don't want to attract the wrong kind of attention.

Please note: I know there's a similar question out there that asks what to do if you come in for an interview after being let go. What makes my situation different is that this got all the way to an offer.

I also see a similar question asked by someone ho changed jobs on their resume. My question s a bit different because I as asked to leave.

Just to add, while I was asked to leave, it was on as good terms as possible (my former manager, who was also the company CEO, even wrote a positive letter of reference) though I'm not sure if it's wise to bring that up.

Update: Sent in a new copy of my resume, turned out to not be a problem at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [employment background check (error due to old version of resume)](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48654/employment-background-check-error-due-to-old-version-of-resume)

Comment: How long have you worked for your current employer?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Only 4 months.

Comment: Did you tell the recruiter that you worked for 4 months at your last company? Or did the entire interview process take place while you were working at your last employer? Off-hand, I'd say that if you worked for anyone for six months or less, you don't have to mention it unless the position that you are going for requires a security clearance. You were asked to leave but if your last employer is not contesting your application for unemployment benefits, I'd say that you were laid off because you weren't a good fit for the company but they recognize your talents. (cont)

Comment: Otherwise, they asked you to leave because you weren't a good fit but they recognize your talents and they are willing to be a reference for you. Until I get more answers from you, I'd say that you have the option of mentioning your last job or not because your employment lasted for less than six months, unless you are applying for a position that requires a security clearance. If you already disclosed to the recruiter that you were at your last company, you have no option but to follow through. As long as you have a good narrative about your being asked to leave, you should be in good shape,

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I mentioned on my resume that it was "present" when I submitted it a month ago. I assume I'll need to have a good narrative then?

Comment: @JohnDoe - Indeed you do but again, as long as your former employer is willing to act as your reference, you should be able to come up with a positive narrative  that your former employer will back up. You are not nor will you be the last to lose their job because you did not fit even though you were qualified.  I was asked to leave once because of poor fit: in my case, the fit was poor because the CEO was a liar and he was also as dumb as a box of rocks. My main challenge afterwards was explaining why I was told to leave while leaving out the "liar" and the "dumb as a box rocks" parts :)

Answer (score 6):

> Should I proactively send an updated resume to the recruiter upon
>   accepting the offer, explaining the situation, or should I simply
>   accept the offer as it's made and not say anything?

If they are going to perform a background check *based on the resume you already gave them* and if that resume is out of date, it only makes sense to give them an updated, correct resume.

The last thing you want is to be rejected because your resume didn't reflect reality and it was detected during the background check. You'll look like you have something to hide, or are a liar.

Comment: +1 - you don't want to look deceitful. Get them an updated resume now.

Answer (score 4):

This would depend on if the resume was up to date when you sent it. If it was and you got sacked afterwards I wouldn't mention it, there's no dishonesty there and mentioning you got sacked is not a great idea if you don't have to.

If the resume was totally wrong right from the start, then yes, you need to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what background checking company your new employer will use, but the last time that I had one done the dates on pretty much all of my jobs were "guess-timations" and they had to verify all of them and left notes on the background check like "said he worked for X from APR 2009 to JUN 2012 and it was actually MAR 2009 to MAY 2012"... I got the offer anyway.

I don't think that they're really looking for 100% accuracy... and as long as you left your last job amicably I wouldn't worry too much about it. If it comes up at some point just be honest and say that things had changed since you sent them your resume.